# Storing USER ID in PHP SESSION

Tags: php, html, mysql, security, session

I am working on a WEB-APP for Smartphone and am having a few questions with the log-in procedure.

Assuming that a user has already registered, the first thing a user needs to do on my website is log into the portal with a username and password. 
That username and password is sent to a php login function that checks the information is correct based on salt values etc.
If the information is correct the following items are created and the user is logged in.

```
$_SESSION['user']=$id;
$cookieLifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // A year in seconds
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$cookieLifetime);
```

Later in the website, the user makes calls using the session to the database to pull information relevant to that user.

For example, I am building a client manager system for AGENTS where AGENTS can store client information into our database. Each client has an AGENT ID associated to it which is the ID and AGENT receives when registering on the site, and this ID is also stored in the session when the AGENT is logged in.
When the agent logs into their portal, the php script makes a database call and returns all clients that are associated to the agent id number.

Is it possible for anyone to tamper with the session ID? If so, what can i do to fix it?

Comment: PHP is not my cup of tea, but are you sure you have to create that cookie yourself?

Comment: Arjan that cookie was created for the iphone web application, I am about to reduce its time.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying/asking. I see *"Is it possible for anyone to tamper with the session ID?"*, which is probably already answered somewhere on SO. But you're also showing you're creating your own cookie, so are probably getting/restoring (or even *creating*...?) the session yourself based on that cookie, rather than having the framework (or PHP) get the session for you? And the part about the agents seems to be unrelated?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few hints (you didn't provide details that have to be fixed):

Don't use Session-IDs in GET-Vars

Provide a logout button that kills the session.

Reduce the session timeout value (e.g. 30 minutes).

The cookieLifetime value doesn't matter because the session is invalid before the cookie expires.

Comment: Thank you, the only time I pass an ID in the URL with GET is for a client profile such as profile.php?id=5.. But when on that link I do a few checks to make sure the session ID matches the one for the assigned agent ID in the client database row etc. I also check to make sure the correct user is logged in to view that profile, if not they are redirected away.

Comment: I have also createad a logout button for agents. Thank you for your help